# JavaScript: screenshot rendered web page Browser style

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, web, screenshot

I assume this question might have been asked before but after hours of searching, I haven't found anything satisfying.

Here's my question: Is it possible to screenshot a fully rendered web page using JavaScript? A little like what most browsers do on windows on the press of `ctrl+p`.

I have looked into a lot of alternative solutions like [html2Canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
 but none suits my needs. The biggest issue being my web page almost entirely rendered on client side using Javascript. This is also why server side solution like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) are hardly applicable.

I need the screenshots to be printed as image or PDF.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: "The biggest issue being my web page almost entirely rendered on client side using Javascript. This is also why server side solution like PhantomJS are hardly applicable." - Why? PhantomJS is fully capable of executing your page's JS. Alternately, you could AJAX the currently rendered HTML to the server and let it render that static snapshot for you. AFAIK there are no good clientside solutions (although html2Canvas seems to come rather close). If you say they don't suit your needs, you need to say why, or we can't come up with any solutions.

Comment: Hey @Amadan and thanks for your answer. 
I know phantomJs is fully capable of executing my pages however, the pages are entirely rendered on the client side using the client credentials to generate the correct data. The credentials are read from a PHP session variable. 

I tried rendering the page and then sending the HTML back to the server for PhantomJS to process, but then it crashes everytime due to the size of the HTML (The pages are huge). And so far; I haven't found a way to pass the session variable to PhantomJS.

Comment: Sessions are identified by cookies. Replicate the cookie ([`phantom.addCookie`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/add-cookie.html)), and you get your session.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Puppeteer by Google](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)?

If you're able to run it on your server, it might be exactly what you're looking for. See their example code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```